# 'Set' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. (TS2693)

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code for checking if array has duplicates.

```
let arr: number[] = [1,2,3,1];

function hasDuplicates (arr: number[]): boolean {
  return new Set(arr).size !== arr.length;
}
```

But here I encounter typescript compiler error

```
'Set' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here. (TS2693)
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Set` was added as part of ES6. If you are targetting ES5 or lower, you will get this error.

You can fix this by either upgrading your target to `es6` in `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    // ...
}
```

Or if you don't want to change your target, but you want your code to compile add `es6` to your `lib` options:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es6"],
    // ...
}
```

Do note that with this approach if the runtime environment does not support the `Set` class, then it will throw a runtime error.

Comment: Alternatively, if you need only sets from `es6` lib you can use `es2015.collection` instead.